# Puppet - How do I define the sequence of when the code on modules are run?

Tags: module, manifest, puppet

I have several modules that need to run in a specific sequence, how do I specify this ?
Also how do I specify the sequence of classes and commands inside one module ?

Found an answer to this myself

using

`require => File['something']`

and

```
require class
```

Answer (score 1):

Also you can set the sequence using ->
For example:

```
node 'example.com' {
  class { 'foo' :
  } ->
  class { 'bar' :
  }
}
```

class bar will be applied after class foo.

Notify and subscribe also affect to applying sequence. See http://docs.puppetlabs.com/learning/ordering.html